# assign expression to a variable and use in ng-class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<td ng-repeat="date in dates" ng-class="{'sunday': date | amDateFormat:'ddd' === 'Sun' }">
   {{date | amDateFormat:'ddd'}}
</td>
```

The `{{date | amDateFormat:'ddd'}}` above output `Mon, Tue etc..` but above code got me an error.

I'm thinking how to assign `{{date | amDateFormat:'ddd'}}` to something for me to do my conditioning for ng-class. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parentheses `()` in condition

```
<td ng-repeat="date in dates" 
    ng-class="{'sunday': (date | amDateFormat:'ddd') === 'Sun' }">
       {{date | amDateFormat:'ddd'}}
</td>
```